# With node/express/Multer, how do you "first" check a parameter?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I use multer exactly like this,

```
const specialExample = multer({ .. blah blah })
app.post(
    '/specialPath',
    specialExample.single('handled_by_multer'),
    await function (req, res) {
        fs.renameSync(.. move the file, etc
        // send a reply
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        res.status(200).send(`ok`)
    })
```

So note that things happen in this order:

```
app.post(
    '/specialPath',
// EXPRESS KNOWS TO GO THIS WAY
    specialExample.single('handled_by_multer'),
// MULTER LITERALLY IS GETTING THE FILE
// MULTER HAS COMPLETELY GOT AND SAVED THE FILE
    await function (req, res) {
// THIS FUNCTION NOW BEGINS RUNNING
        ... etc
```

That's all perfectly fine.

Now, imagine I want to look at some parameter.

In some cases I **DO NOT** want to get the file.

```
const specialExample = multer({ .. blah blah })
app.post(
    '/specialPath',
    specialExample.single('handled_by_multer'),
    await function (req, res) {
        const meta = req.body.meta
        if (meta !== "wth") {
           .. we actually DON'T want the  file
           .. delete the file
           .. send a 401 and return
        }
        fs.renameSync(.. move the file, etc
        // send a reply
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        res.status(200).send(`ok`)
    })
```

Note that that works fine, BUT, we are wastefully getting/saving the file (and only then deleting it).

Is there a way to do something more like this .......

```
app.post(
    '/specialPath',

    await function (req, res) {
        .. if I happen to want to, only then: {
            specialExample.single('handled_by_multer'),
        }
    })
```

How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `multer` is the middleware that's (also) parsing the field data that gets stored in `req.body`, you can't conditionally call it.

Instead, you can use Multer's [`fileFilter`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter) to ignore the file data if your conditions are met:

```
const specialExample = multer({
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    const meta = req.body.meta;
    if (meta !== "wth") {
      // reject this file
      return cb(null, false);
    }
    return cb(null, true);
  },
  .. blah blah
});
...
app.post(
    '/specialPath',
    specialExample.single('handled_by_multer'),
    await function (req, res) {
      // also have to check here to make sure the correct response is sent
      const meta = req.body.meta
      if (meta !== "wth") {
        return res.sendStatus(401);
      }
      ...
    }
);
```

One possible issue: the field(s) that you depend on to check if the file should be rejects (`meta` in this example) needs to be placed into the multipart data *before* the file data, otherwise it won't be populated by the time `fileFilter()` is called.

Comment: RK , great, thanks, I didn't know about fileFilter.  I'll give it a go.  (As you may know, fileName seems to be buggy/tricky, folks report it not working, and I couldn't get it working. I'll see how I go with fileFilter!)  Thanks!

Comment: That's an amazing tip about adding the form fields actually before the file, who would have known ?!

Comment: hello, it seems that if you indeed return `false` in the `fileFilter`. Then in fact. In the path code, it seems you get `req.file === undefined`.  Thus, you can check for that rather than "performing the same check again" (in my case it was a very heavy / slow check, so it's handy).  Amazing!

Comment: @Fattie yeah you could use that, or be a bit more explicit and add a flag to `req` (say `req._dontContinue`) to indicate that the request should fail. Both the `fileFilter` function and your request handler will receive the same `req` instance.

Comment: great point about adding to `req.`  thanks a million for the amazing answer, I've noticed few people have expertise in this field. bounty en route :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the amazing @robertklep answer/comments, you can alternately use

```
        if (req.file === undefined)
```

to branch in the function.

Here's a full example showing

- use `fileFilter` to decide if you want to accept the file or not
- use `storage#diskStorage#destination` (not "dest") to set the directory
- use `storage#diskStorage#filename` function to decide on the filename

So:

```
const examp = multer({

    async fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        // check for say authorization etc
        // to get any params, req.body.yourParameter ... 
        if (permitted === true) {
            return cb(null, true)
        }
        else {
            return cb(null, false)
        }
    },

    storage: multer.diskStorage({

        destination: _some_directory,
        
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            // eg, you want the filename not the random string
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        }
    })
})
```

and then ...

```
app.post(
    '/happyPath',
    examp.single('multer_tag'),
    async function (req, res) {

        if (req.file === undefined) {
            // WE KNOW MULTER SAID 'NO' in fileFilter above
            res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
            res.status(401).send("")
            return
        }

        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        res.status(200).send(`ok`)
    }
)
```

---

*NOTE* `filename` is only available inside `diskStorage` which is a bit silly. (Disk storage seems to be the default anyway.) There are many internet posts "filename is not working in multer". The solution is simple, you have to explicitly include the `diskStorage`.